# JQuery - Call method from string inside plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, polymorphism

I have a plugin:

```
$.fn.formvalidator = function(method) {
```

Which I call:

```
$('form').formvalidator();
```

I have a method that takes in an array of strings:

```
function execute(field, rules) {
    for(i=0; i<rules.length; i++) {
        window[rules[i]](field);
    }
}

rules:
array(
    'required',
    'email'
);
```

Trying to execute each string in the array as a method with a field parameter. I get an error:

```
Unhandled Error: 'window[rules[i]]' is not a function
```

I looked around and I think since I am inside a function declaration formvalidator I cannot use window so I've tried:

```
$.fn.formvalidator[rules[i]](field);
fn.formvalidator[rules[i]](field);
formvalidator[rules[i]](field);
```

But same error. Not sure how to execute this string array as methods.

UPDATE: Clarification

$('form').formvalidator(); invokes the plugins which iterates over all the inputs in the form. Each input element has an attribute data-fv="required|email|other|example" which I grab with:

```
var attributes = $(this).data('fv');
```

Once I get these attributes I split them by a '|' into the rules array. Now for each field input I want to call those strings:

```
window[rules[i]](field); // if rules[0] = 'required' it calls the method below

function required(field) {
    ...
}
```

The $('form').formvalidator(); has nothing to do with what I am trying to accomplish, just added that to show how the plugin is activated.

Answer (score 0):

window is the global object and you are declaring formValidator inside the jQuery object (also know as '$') so you have to call it in this manner:

```
$("form")[rules[i]](field);
```

or possibly:

```
$("form").formValidator(rules[i], field);
```

I can't figure it out since I don't know what formValidator actually does, it accepts functions or strings and what it does with them?

Comment: You're confused, my mistake. Please see my update in a second. Basically each input method can specify rules that the validator plugin reads and verifies. So you can go <input type="text" data-fv="required|min_length[6]"> then the plugin will read that and make sure it has a value of at least 6.

Comment: @user2233440 have you tried 'rules[i](field)' without prefixing 'window'? No nevermind that shouldn't work

Comment: Your functions should be defined in the top level of the javascript file (as in they can't be inside another function unless you declare them as window.required= function() {} )

Comment: I cant have that though, because this is a JQuery plugin? I need it all packaged into one.